# jQuery's .width() result is wrong in Chrome 25, how do I get the real result?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a table that overflows with a scrollbar when the screen isn't big enough.
But I still need to know how wide the *actual* content is.

I used to be able to do:

```
$('table').width()
```

And that would give me the full width of the table content with the scrollbar. It **still** does in Firefox, Chrome 24, ...

But in Chrome 25 it only gives me the width of what I can see.

Here's an example setup. Turn on your console (or try $('table').width() out for yourselves) in Firefox and Chrome 25:

http://public.kipdola.be/chrome-25-jquery-test.html

(By the way, I also tried to get `$('table tr').width()`, but that produces the same result.)

So: which one is right? Is Firefox right for giving the actual size of the content, or is Chrome right for giving the size of what I can see on my screen?

And, more importantly, how do I get the full size of the table content?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `width: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` from your table but add `min-width: 100%` instead.

Comment: No, because when the table actually is smaller than the page, it should stretch out to fill the entire page.

Comment: Yeah, that solves it. (Unfortunately, those are settings in Twitter Bootstrap) So, Chrome is actually doing it correct?

Comment: well considering you set the table's width explicitly to a maximum of 100% of its parent, one could say that chrome is doing it correctly, even if the actual rendered width of the table is more than that...